# How pass more param to editColumn method

Tags: php, laravel-5

in my laravel 5.7 app with yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 8
in control I need to add more parameters to editColumn method and I failed like with wrong syntax:

```
        $colorsCollection            = Color
            ::orderBy('colors.title', 'asc')
            ->get();

        $datatablesCollection = Datatables
            ::of($storageSpacesCollection ) using ($colorsCollection)

            ...

            ->editColumn('id', function ($storageSpace) with ($colorsCollection){
                $current_storage_space_color = '';
                $current_storage_space_title = '';
/*                $colorsCollection            = Color
                    ::orderBy('colors.title', 'asc')
                    ->get();*/
```

How can I do this ?
Thanks!